# "Solution" of finite cluster algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, cluster-algebras

Consider the cluster algebras $A_n$ and $D_n$. Choose any cluster $x$, is there an explicit formula that express all other cluster variables in terms of $x$?

Answer (score 4):

There is a formula for the Laurent expansions of cluster variables in terms of matchings in "snake graphs" for cluster algebras from any surface. For the question type $A$ (a disk with marked points on the boundary) and type $D$ (a once punctured disk with marked points on the boundary) come from surfaces.

[Positivity for cluster algebras from surfaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0748)
 by Musiker, Schiffler, and  Williams has this for any surface. [Cluster expansion formulas and perfect matchings](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.3638) by Musiker and Schiffler has treatment for unpunctured surfaces. These [notes](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~patrick.le-meur/CIMPA/Course-Schiffler.pdf) of Schiffler also treat cluster algebras from surfaces including the Laurent expansion. Canakci and Schiffler also have a series of paper on various aspects of snake graphs.

**Edit addition**: I originally thought of the more general results for surfaces given above. However, if you are particularly interested in the type $A$ Propp's [The combinatorics of frieze patterns and Markoff numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511633) and Schiffler's [A cluster expansion formula (An case)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611956)
 are very nice precursors to the above more general theorems.